# is there frame server software for ubuntu(linux)?

Tags: server, windows, ffmpeg

I use Adobe Premier for editing videos on some client PCs and I want to render my videos on an ubuntu server by ffmpeg commands.In the words instead of rendering the Premier project by it's own encoder I want to do it with ffmpeg on a linux OS. I know that distributing the rendering process can be done by using frame serving . For now the only way that I have found for doing this is using [Debugmode Frameserver](http://www.debugmode.com/frameserver/netserve.htm) along with [AviSynth](http://avisynth.nl/index.php/FAQ_frameserving) . But the problem is that Debugmode Frameserver only has Windows based application however AviSynth is available on linux . 
Now can any one tell me how may I do this . Is there any linux alternative for Debugmode Frameserver or is there any other way for doing this?

Not that I want to do this on a linux server which means it doesn't have any GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this by using ffmpeg, Here are the steps:

1. First do steps of the second method("Use a frameserver") on  this page ("[How to encode with ffmpeg from Adobe Premiere Pro](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/PremierePro)")
2. Beginng this step you should be streaming your Premier timeline through Debugmode and Avisynth on a specific IP and port. Now open a command line and run this ffmpeg command:

`ffmpeg -i frameserver.avs -f mpegts  tcp://[IP address of your server]:[open port on your server]`

by running this command you are sendnig Avisynth output(streaming) to a distination machine(your linux server) throught ffmpeg.
After this step all you have to do on the client server(where you edit your videos) is done , now let's go to the server side.

3. on the server (your linux server) simply run the below ffmpeg command and you are done:(assumung you have ffmpeg installed on your server)
   `ffmpeg -i tcp://[your server IP]:[The same port you entered in step 2]?listen -c:v libx264 -preset medium -crf 23 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a libfdk_aac -vbr 4 output2.mp4`

by this command ffmpeg will be listenning on a specified IP and port and recieving sent packets and encode them with your favorite options!

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand how Debugmode Frameserver and AviSynth interact in your usecase. Is AviSynth listening on a port or socket on the target machine where Debugmode Frameserver sends the data to? I didn't know that AviSynth could do that.

I know that AviSynth is a frameserver itself built for Windows. There have been a several efforts to bring AviSynth functionality to Linux or make it cross platform, the latest and most promising one is [VapourSynth](http://www.vapoursynth.com/).

If Debugmode Frameserver needs to run on the target machine to try using it with Wine. A few years back running AviSynth with Wine was tricky though somehow possible and stable, but VapourSynth was more reliable and less painful on Windows last time I tried. Since then all necessary parts seem to have been ported to VapourSynth to make filters like QTGMC work natively.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In fact you install Debugmode Frameserver to frameserve from Premier to  AviSynth. In the other words , Debugmode is recommended compatible frameserver for doing this. now my problem is that Debugmode is not available on linux. So what is the way for frameserving from Premier to a linux OS ?

Comment: Install Debugmode through Wine should be the solution, if I understand you correctly, and then let it handoff to VapourSynth if possible. There is even a PPA for it as I just found out: https://launchpad.net/~djcj/+archive/ubuntu/vapoursynth

Comment: I think that it is not possible, is it? because I am talking about a linux server which only has command line ,so how can I install Debug mode via wine in command line . besides the face that Debug mod only has GUI version .

Comment: That depends, having access to a GUI just in case would be better (so if it's possible, install a desktop package, the desktop version or something small like openbox). If you don't need a GUI to configure or install (some installers usually support "silent" switches) anything then it's possible to run everything from terminal using Wine (I do that with x264.exe). Also if you need to configure something in Wine through GUI that you would never touch afterwards you can do the configuration on one box where you have desktop packages installed and copy the wine folder to the server afterwards.